# swift 4 error: load html string to webview

Tags: html, swift, webview

I tried to load a html string in my webview with the code :

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "code", ofType: "html")
        let html = try! String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.weview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

I run the app, everything works fine, but if i press on a website link, i get the error in my AppDelegate: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)`
Can someone give me a code for swift 4, where I can load a html string and interact with it? Would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
let link = "https://google.co.in"
do {
    let htmlStr = try String(contentsOf : URL(string:link)!)
    let separateHtmlStr = htmlStr.components(separatedBy:"") // any html tag you want to interact with

    let newURL = URL(string: link)
    yourWebView.loadHTMLString(separateHtmlStr, baseURL: newURL) // in case if you have changed anything

   }catch{
        print("Exception")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check - go to `Project Settings -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources` to make sure your directory with your html-files is on the list there.

Second, load the file the way listed below. You don't have to load the content of the file.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "code", ofType: "html")!
let uri = URL(string: path)!
let request = URLRequest(url: uri)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Also, make sure `forResource` param contains full path to the html file starting from your project directory